# Why do I get a SIGSEGV with this unconditional jump?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, segmentation-fault

I tried to run this code on Linux to see what would happen:

```
int fn(void) { return 0; }
int main(void) { __asm__("jmp fn;"); }
```

I don't see any reason for the execution to be terminated by a SIGSEGV, but that's what I get. I expected the flow to be redirected to `_start` since the stack isn't modified in any way inside `main` and `fn` and the return address inside the activation record should still be "usable".

Can you please explain what's behind this?

Comment: `since the stack isn't modified in any way inside main` This is not correct. Take a look at the assembly code.

Comment: This is because when you reach the end of fn(), it pops the return address from the stack, but it was not pushed there before since you "jumped" there instead of "calling" there.

Comment: Generate the assembly output and look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return 0` generates something like

```
mov $0x0, %eax
ret
```

where `ret` **pops the return address from the stack** and jumps there. A simple `jmp` doesn't push any return address, so `ret` will pop whatever is on the stack.

Comment: More specifically, he'd want to replace `jmp` with `call` and things will work as expected.